# A linear algebra problem regarding rank

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why there is solution of $A^TAx=A^Tb$ always ? How to show that the rank of coefficient matrix and augmented matrix is same always ? I understand that the matrix $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite.

Another question is how to do the same for $(A^TA + \lambda I)x=A^Tb$ ?

Comment: You need to mention that this is over the real numbers. It is not true over other fields.

Answer (score 2):

First, $A^\top Ax\cdot x = Ax\cdot Ax\ge 0$ for all $x$.

As for your first question, there are various proofs. For example, $\text{Im}(A)=(\ker A^\top)^\perp$, so $(\ker A^\top)\cap \text{Im}(A)=\{0\}$. This, together with $\text{Im}(A^\top A)\subset \text{Im}(A^\top)$, gives equality of the subspaces $\text{Im}(A^\top A)$ and $\text{Im}(A^\top)$.

Comment: I am new to linear algebra. What is the necessary condition for $Ax=b$ has a solution in terms of linear maps ? You showed that $rank(A^TA)=rank(A^T)$. whereas I have to show that $rank(A^TA)=rank(A^TAA^T)$ Actually, I have not followed your argument properly. Can you elaborate it ?

Comment: A word for the future: If you give as much of the argument as you can, we will have a better idea of what you know and what notation you use. I still really do not know. I showed more than the rank equality. Where did you get this rank statement you say "whereas I have to show ..."? Until you tell me what notations and basic results you are familiar with, I can't really elaborate. This is a standard result proved in most linear algebra texts when they discuss the normal equations for solving inconsistent systems.

Comment: sorry, I understood it now. I tried to form a augmented matrix like that which was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant result is that $\mathbb{R}^n = {\cal R} A \oplus \ker A^T$.

So we can write $b = b_1+b_2$, where $b_1 \in {\cal R} A$ and $b_2 \in \ker A^T$.

Since $b_1 \in {\cal R} A$, there is some $x$ such that $Ax = b_1$. Hence $Ax-b_1 = b_2 \in  \ker A^T$, or equivalently, $A^T(Ax-b_1) = 0$. Since $b_2 \in  \ker A^T$, we have $A^T b_2 = 0$, so we can subtract them to get 
$$A^T(Ax-b_1) - A^T b_2= 0 = A^T(Ax-b)$$

To see why the ranks are the same, note that $\ker A = \ker (A^T A)$. It is straightforward to see that $\ker A \subset \ker (A^T A)$. Suppose $x \in \ker (A^T A)$. Then $A^TA x = 0$, and hence $x^T A^T A x = \|Ax \|^2 = 0$, from which we get $x \in \ker A$.

Comment: If I can prove existence of such $x$ (shown in many of the answers) then I am done. What is the implication of $Rank(A^TA)=Rank(A^T)$, in fact, $Range(A^TA)=Range(A^T)$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the existence of $x$. If $y \in {\cal R} A$, then, by definition, there must exist some $x$ such that $Ax=y$. The essential feature you need to be aware of is the decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in terms of the range space of $A$ and the null space of $A^T$.

Comment: @Copper.Hat $Ax-b_1 =b_2$??I am a bit confused.Also forgive me if this sounds dumb, but $Ax-b_1 \in Ker(A^t)$  iff $A^tAx =A^tb_1$ right??So we are already assuming that ???And how does the fact that $A^t$ acts on the dual of the image space tie in here?I get the reasoning after that.Thanks

Comment: You can always write $b=b_1+b_2$ where $b_1 \in {\cal R} A$, and $b_2 \in \ker A^T$. This is the essential fact. Then $Ax-b = (Ax-b_1)-b_2$, and by 'construction' (of $b_1$) there exists some $x$ such that $Ax=b_1$, and so we have $Ax-b = -b_2$, and since $b_2 \in \ker A^T$, we have $A^T(Ax-b_1) = 0$. Again, since $b_2 \in \ker A^T$, we can 'pop it back' into $A^T(Ax-b_1) = 0$ to get $A^T(Ax-b_1-b_2) = 0 = A^T(Ax-b)$.